# Helm pass/se environment variable into container on helm upgrade

Tags: environment-variables, containers, kubernetes-helm

I try to upgrade helm chart which installed in k8s
with this command :

```
helm upgrade vault hashicorp/vault --namespace vault-foo-f my-values.yaml --set VAULT_CACERT=/foo/vault.ca
```

but when I do:

```
helm upgrade vault hashicorp/vault --namespace vault-foo-f my-values.yaml --set VAULT_CACERT=/foo/vault.ca --dry-run >> dry_run3.txt
```

I can't find in the yaml the env: by the name of VAULT_CACERT

and of course, it wasn't set in the pod .

I don't what to uninstall the pods just to upgrade them with the new environment variable

**UPDATE**
this is the helm values.yaml i have this [helm chart](https://github.com/hashicorp/vault-helm):

the problem is that this part never set the env var in the container

```
 extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca
```

```
global:
  enabled: true
  tlsDisable: false
  extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca
server:
  extraSecretEnvironmentVars:
    - envName: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      secretName: eks-creds
      secretKey: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - envName: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      secretName: eks-creds
      secretKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  extraVolumes:
  - type: secret
    name: vault-tls

  ha:
    enabled: true
    replicas: 3
    raft:
      enabled: true
      setNodeId: false
      config: |
        ui = true
        serviceType: "LoadBalancer"
           serviceNodePort: null
           externalPort: 8200

        listener "tcp" {
          address = "0.0.0.0:8200"
          cluster_address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
          tls_cert_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.crt"
          tls_key_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.key"
          tls_client_ca_file = "/vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca"
        }

        storage "raft" {
          path = "/vault/data"
        }
        
        service_registration "kubernetes" {}
```

Comment: Can you show the template code that references `.Values.VAULT_CACERT`?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You need to `--set global.extraEnvironmentVariables.VAULT_CACERT=...`, not just the bottommost key.  It might be a little cleaner to include this in the `my-values.yaml`, which gets passed via the `vault upgrade -f` option.

Comment: but i did! and the key is not set in the container !
see in the yaml :
 extraEnvironmentVars:
    VAULT_CACERT: /vault/userconfig/vault-tls/vault.ca